# Apply single statefile using salt-call

Tags: salt-stack

Is there a way to apply a single statefile?
I would very much like to do a salt-call locally and apply a single file, equivalent of puppet-apply /tmp/some-manifest.pp

I would very much like to keep it in single file and not change salt roots or paths etc.

Answer (score 5):

In master mode, if you have a `common/users.sls` file in your salt root, you can use:

```
salt-call state.sls common.users
```

In standalone mode, you can use `salt-call --local` if the salt root is configured. See https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/quickstart.html